# How to show an ASP.NET validation message next to my Save button as well as next to the validated control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, customvalidator

I'm using asp CustomValidator to perform client-side validation on a few controls when the user clicks the Save button on a page. However, this page is quite long so often they can't see the validation message that's displayed next to a control that fails validation. How can I put a general validation message next to the Save button too, e.g. 'Please resolve the validation errors above' so the user knows why the page hasn't submitted?

Comment: Dude go for validation summary .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Validation Summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) control, which you can put near your save button and it will provide a summary of all the validation controls that are invalid.

You can define it using the following rules:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary 
     id="programmaticID" 
     DisplayMode="BulletList | List | SingleParagraph" 
     EnableClientScript="true | false"
     ShowSummary="true | false"
     ShowMessageBox="true | false"                        
     HeaderText="You need to resolve the following issues before you are able to continue:"
     runat="server"/>
```